# How to show stock availability information in the product grid on Magento?

Tags: magento

I have a question about the product category view. As I have out of stock products showing (Needs to be like this as we are a wholesaler) I would like it displayed so that the customer can see if it is in stock before drilling down into the detailed product page.

Please see attached what part I would like to see on the category page:

[Link to image of idea: http://ipseitycore.co.uk/screen.jpg](http://ipseitycore.co.uk/screen.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Try the line of code below in the list template (catalog/product/list.phtml):

```
<?php
   $qty = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();
   echo $qty;
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that code, but I would like it to be in the style of the product details page. So it has a darker background with a little icon. Do you know how to add this?

Answer (score 1):

I actually had this code added to just show "Out of stock" or "Only 1 left". For my website, I didn't need "In Stock" to show.

```
    <span class="out-of-stock">
         <?php 
                $qty = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();
                if ($qty == 1) :
                    echo $this->__('Only 1 left in stock!');
                elseif ($qty == 0) :
                    echo $this->__('Out of stock!');
                else :
                    echo $this->__('&nbsp;');
                endif;
        ?>
   </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in list.phtml file

```
<?php  $ObjectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $StockState = $ObjectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');
    echo $StockState->getStockQty($_product->getId(), $_product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
?>
```

Comment: This answer is for Magento2 - and in Magento2 you must never call the object manager directly in template files.